# cloned android source from github but can't compile it

Tags: android

I just used `repo` to clone the android source via the following commands

```
repo init -u git://github.com/android/platform_manifest.git --repo-url=git://github.com/android/tools_repo.git
repo sync
```

I now have a directory layout that looks like this:

```
~/android-src/
     bionic
     build
     dalvik
     development
     external
     frameworks
     hardware
     packages
     prebuilt
     system
```

from `~/android-src/` I ran `. build/envsetup.sh` and than used `lunch` to select a build configuration.

I than tried to run `make` as described in the google build instructions [here](http://source.android.com/source/building.html), however I have no idea where to run `make` from. I have no make file in my `~/android-src` folder and executing `m` doesn't find a makefile either.

I'm really confused as to how to actually start compiling the android source and trying to find relevant information on the web has been frustrating.

Update:
Based on the below answer from Yuri (which I tried previously as wel) I am now getting this when running `repo sync`

```
Initializing project platform/abi/cpp ...
fatal: '../platform/abi/cpp.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: Cannot fetch platform/abi/cpp
```

So it appears either the directions are wrong or there is something wrong with their repo. Or am I missing something?

Comment: AFAIK, `lunch` should have created a makefile in `~/android-src`. Perhaps `lunch` didn't really run?

Comment: When I run lunch with no arguments it gives me three build config options and appears to work successfully, but doesn't appear to actually be doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several comments to your question.

1. First of all why are you downloading the source code from github? There is already official repository available. The code now is hosted on Google servers. Read [this](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) how to download it.
2. You should run make command from the `/android-src` folder. In this folder there is a `Makefile` that points to `build/core/main.mk`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So 1) As of a few hours ago this was still borked due to the kernel.org hack. 2) There is no makefile there

Comment: @Casey: The kernel.org issue was fixed a couple of weeks ago, insofar as it is no longer hosted at kernel.org. However, you are using the wrong code base, as Yury noted. Do not use github.com. Use the instructions he linked to.

Comment: So I trashed my entire android-src folder as well as the `.repo` directory and followed Google's directions that you linked too. See above update for why this isn't working.

Comment: You should delete your android-src folder completely and then create it once again. After that cd to this directory, initialize repo and run repo sync    It seems to me that there are conflicts with the github repository.

Comment: And I hope that you use repo tool provided by Google. Check this. On the same web page you can find instructions.

Comment: @Yury - done and I'm using the same repo tool from that page. Just downloaded it all again and retried the google instructions. Same result.

Comment: Ok, I just deleted everything again, including the downloaded repo tool. Redid the steps on that page and it seems that the code is downloading correctly.

Comment: I think now everything should be ok. However, sometimes the sources are downloaded partially and in this case also a problem with build can arise.